# Cannot delete a wav file after it has been opened, java

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, memory-leaks, delete-file

I want a sound file (temp0x) of wav format to be edited/deleted after it has been opened. I'm using a thread to play the sound, and close all streams when done. The main thread then should delete it, but it fails to do so. If I do not play the sound first there is no problem with deleting it.

This is the code in the playSound thread that plays the sound:

```
public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
        System.out.println("play sound: " + soundFile.getName());

        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info info;

        try {
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            format = stream.getFormat();
            info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(stream);
            clip.start();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(clip.getMicrosecondLength() != clip.getMicrosecondPosition()){
        //waiting for sound to be finished  
        }

        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
            public void update(LineEvent myLineEvent) {
              if (myLineEvent.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP)
                clip.close();
            }
          });
        soundFile = null;
        clip = null;
        stream = null;


        notify();
    }
}
```

this is the code in my main thread:

```
PlaySound playSound = new PlaySound(filePath);
    Thread play = new Thread(playSound);
    play.start();

    synchronized(play){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for play to complete...");
            play.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("play done");
    }

    if(new File("Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav").delete()){
        System.out.println("deleted");
    } else
        System.out.println("cannot delete");


}
```

it prints cannot delete. I'v been staring at it for hours and googling my socks of but I cannot find a solution. Can anybody help me out?

EDIT::

If i change the boolean delete check as suggested this is my output (English: no acces since file already used by other proces):

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: src\Opslaan.wav: Het proces heeft geen toegang tot het bestand omdat het door een ander proces wordt gebruikt.

at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

EDIT::
problem seems platform dependent. I need a solution for Windows.

Comment: You might want to try separating out your File creation (`new File("Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav).delete())`, from your call to `delete`.  Then make sure the file exists and the path is correct prior to calling `delete`.

Comment: First, change `new File("Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav").delete()` to `Files.delete(Paths.get("Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav"))`.  That way, instead of a cryptic boolean, you will get an informative exception that should give you a lot more detail about why the file cannot be deleted.  Second, Object.wait() must *always* be called in a loop;  see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) for details.

Comment: At OS X, I don't experience any issues at all. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time, little bit different

PlaySound.java

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class PlaySound implements Runnable {

    BufferedInputStream soundFile;
    Clip clip;
    AudioInputStream stream;

    public PlaySound(String file) throws Exception {
        // we have to create InputStream by ourselves
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        soundFile = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){

        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info info;

        try {
            // we pass stream instead of file
            // it looks like getAudioInputStream messes around with
            // file
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            format = stream.getFormat();
            info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(stream);
            clip.start();
            while(clip.getMicrosecondLength() != clip.getMicrosecondPosition()) {}
            // we can close everything by ourselves
            clip.close();
            stream.close();
            soundFile.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 

        soundFile = null;
        clip = null;
        stream = null;

        notifyAll();
      }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] arg) throws Exception {

        String filePath = "Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav";
        PlaySound playSound = new PlaySound(filePath);
        Thread play = new Thread(playSound);
        play.start();
        try {
            play.join();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStacktrace(); 
        }

        System.out.println("play done");
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("Sounds/Custom", "temp0x.wav"); 
        try {
           Files.delete(path);
        } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
           System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
        } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
           System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
        } catch (IOException x) {
          // File permission problems are caught here.
          System.err.println(x);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This time, after execution, file is removed (at Windows 7).

Comment: it works! however, it is so slow that my program isnt usable anymore... :( (not these code parts but the whole thing with GUI etc.) I had a look at the memory load, but this doesn't seem to increase tha much, only up to 30% or so when playing a sound. But if this realy is due to a Windows problem, I can only try and build around it. Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Main.java

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] arg) {

        String filePath = "Sounds/Custom/temp0x.wav";
        PlaySound playSound = new PlaySound(filePath);
        Thread play = new Thread(playSound);
        play.start();

        synchronized(play){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for play to complete...");
            play.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("play done");
        }

        if(new File(filePath).delete()){
        System.out.println("deleted");
        } else {
        System.out.println("cannot delete");
        }
    }
}
```

PlaySound.java

```
import java.lang.Runnable;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class PlaySound implements Runnable {

    File soundFile;
    Clip clip;
    AudioInputStream stream;

    public PlaySound(String file) {
        soundFile = new File(file);
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
        System.out.println("play sound: " + soundFile.getName());

        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info info;

        try {
            stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            format = stream.getFormat();
            info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(stream);
            clip.start();

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(clip.getMicrosecondLength() != clip.getMicrosecondPosition()){
        //waiting for sound to be finished  
        }

        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
            public void update(LineEvent myLineEvent) {
              if (myLineEvent.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP)
            clip.close();
            }
          });
        soundFile = null;
        clip = null;
        stream = null;


        notify();
      }
    }
}
```

Execute

```
> javac PlaySound.java
> javac Main.java
> java Main
Waiting for play to complete...
play sound: sound.wav
play done
deleted
```

Directory layout

```
.
├── Main.class
├── Main.java
├── PlaySound$1.class
├── PlaySound.class
├── PlaySound.java
└── Sounds
    └── Custom
        └── temp0x.wav
```

Windows7

It really looks like system dependent issue :) Interesting.

[image]

Comment: I just don't understand... is this maybe platform dependend? I'm using Windows 7. this is what I get when I run on my pc:   Waiting for play to complete...
play sound: Opslaan.wav
play done
cannot delete

Comment: This doesnt work for me. Its the same code i send. See original question: EDIT section.